# Using curl with OpenWhisk

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, serverless-framework, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I am trying to use IBM OpenWhisk. It has its own CLI, but I wanted to invoke a simple "echo" sample using `curl`.

```
curl -d-data '{"message": "hellow world"}' https://user:password@openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net:443/api/v1/namespaces/whisk.system/action/samples/echo
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '"message": "hello world"'
{
  "error": "HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: GET",
  "code": 81107
}
```

How can I invoke it OpenWhisk via curl or similar tools, how do I authenticate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Authentication is done via [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), hence you can use the [`-u`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u) flag in curl. Using the `user:pass@url` version as you used it should work aswell.

To invoke an action you have to use `POST`, hence [`-XPOST`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X). Also, the API expects `application/json` as the Content-Type. Data is sent via the [`-d`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) flag in curl.

You also have a typo in your url. You need to use `actions` instead of `action` (the whole [API](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/reference.md#rest-api) uses plurals).

All in all, your request should look like this:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"message": "hello world"}' -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD https://openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net/api/v1/namespaces/whisk.system/actions/samples/echo
```

There is a [blog article](https://amanoblog.wordpress.com/2016/03/03/ibm-bluemix-openwhisk-rest-api/) covering this topic. For blocking actions just add `?blocking=true` as parameter.

Comment: How do I add the "blocking" property?

Comment: Blocking is a query parameter. Simply add `?blocking=true`.

Answer (score 4):

The wsk CLI has also the very handy "-v" option which shows you the HTTP request and headers so if you do:

```
wsk -v action invoke hello --blocking
```

you'll see the actual REST API call.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is done via Basic Authentication. Add an HTTP Header for 'Authorization'. Use the string

```
'Basic'+base64Encoded(username+':'+password)
```

where base64Encoded(str) is a method to base64 encrypt a string.

You can find the username and password for your OpenWhisk account on Bluemix via https://console.ng.bluemix.net/openwhisk/learn/cli
or via wsk cli: wsk property get
it contains the 'whisk auth' property which is in the format 'username:password'